# JDBC cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm trying to use the `@JDBC` annotation in my class definition as below, but Eclipse says `JDBC cannot be resolved to a type`. Why is that so?

I'm using MySQL as database engine and I've added the `mysql-connector-java` to `WEB-INF/lib` and added it to the Build Path of the project.

There's no option to import anything when I click on the lighbulb with an X on red square on the same line of code - just the `Create annotation JDBC`.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@JDBC
public class MyClass {
...
}
```

Comment: add sql.jdbc.jar to youor class path

Comment: did you imported it? can you post the entire code, imports and eclipse build path?

Comment: @mael
I've only imported `import javax.sql.DataSource;` at this early point. I've added `mysql-connector-java` to the Build Path of the project. As for the code - that's pretty much it. I haven't coded anything into the class yet.

Comment: I don't see the import of `@JDBC` and I don't think `javax.sql.DataSource` contains the annotation `@JDBC`.

Comment: @evanwong

I thought it did. What should I import to make it recognize the annotation?

Comment: Why is everyone talking about the annotation as if it really exist in either Java EE or JDBC APIs? This annotation doesn't exist in Java EE nor JDBC at all. It's either homegrown or from a 3rd party library. user1701467, please mention where you learnt about this proprietary annotation, perhaps you've simply read the tutorial/resource/book the wrong way. The above comments and the upvotes collected so far make mainly no sense. There's nothing new here.

Comment: I Googled somewhat, trying to find misleading tutorials; was it [this tutorial](http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet/JSP_tutorial_:_Adding_MySQL_and_JDBC_to_bookstore_example)? Did you **read** this tutorial from top to bottom, also the text and not only the code?

Comment: @BalusC you are right. It doesn't exist in the default java EE/JDBC implementation. He needs to import it from the right library either 3rd party or homegrown. I think I was just pointing out that he didn't import the annotation that he was using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This annotation does **not** exist in [Java EE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/) nor in [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) at all.

Given the combination MySQL + JDBC + Java EE + Eclipse, you were likely following [this tutorial](http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet/JSP_tutorial_%3a_Adding_MySQL_and_JDBC_to_bookstore_example) and copypasting code without reading the text. It mentions the following:

> Also notice that we defined a new annotation called @JDBC. This allows us to inject the right repository into the Servlets as follows:
>
> ```
> package com.bookstore;
>
> import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
> import java.lang.annotation.Target;
> import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
> import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.*;
>
> import javax.inject.Qualifier;
>
> @Qualifier @Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
> public @interface JDBC {
> }
> ```

So, you've got to create it *yourself*.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to actually _find_ the @JDBC reference :-)