# employeesRepo is null when trying to list employees from a database table on a .jsp page

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

My small project uses a database table that contains data about employees(name, phone, email). It provides front-end managment(insert news employee, edit current, remove existing) of the list of employees via a web browser.

Whenever I run my project(to display the list of all employees) on the Tomcat server from Eclipse I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.myproject.crud.EmployeesListServlet.doGet(EmployeesListServlet.java:24)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Line 24: `request.setAttribute("employeess", employeesRepo.listEmployeess());`

**EmployeesListServlet**

```
package com.myproject.crud;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/employees/")
public class EmployeesListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject @JDBC
    private EmployeesRepository employeesRepo;

    public EmployeesListServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("employeess", employeesRepo.listEmployeess());
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/employees-listing.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

Comment: [This (basic) kind of exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) will be thrown when the code is trying to access a reference which is actually `null`. You didn't point out the line clearly (are you new to Java? I'd invest some more time in learning basic Java before diving into servlets...), but I'll assume that it's `employeesRepo` which is `null` and hence the `listEmployeess()` call failed. Is this true? If so, then `@Inject @JDBC` simply didn't do its job. You'd obviously need to edit your question to show how exactly you configured it.

Comment: There's a million questions on here about null pointer exceptions, but none I could find were sufficiently generic to close as a duplicate. You should really try reading a couple of them though. Or at least learn to read the error log.

Comment: The source code you posted for `EmployeesListServlet` appears not to correspond directly to the Stacktrace snippet you posted, as it is 32 lines and references `EmployeesListServlet.java:33`.

Comment: By the way... Tomcat is a barebones JSP/Servlet container, not a Java EE application server (JBoss AS, Glassfish, Resin, etc real Java EE app servers). Tomcat by default doesn't ship with CDI at all. How exactly did you get `@Inject` to "work" in Tomcat in first place?

Comment: The error line is 24: `request.setAttribute("employeess", employeesRepo.listEmployeess());`. I have no idea why the employeesRepo ends up empty since there are no source code errors and, at least to me, the code seems in order. I know what `Nullpointer` exception is, I just have no idea why  it would be null in the first place.

Comment: @BalusC
I imported `import javax.inject.Inject;`

Comment: As to the error, the way how you formulated the question ("Why do I get a NPE?" instead of "Why is employeesRepo null?") indicates otherwise. As to the import, you can import anything. Whether it will do its job is a different story. There's really no magic.

Comment: It is null because you are using dependency injection `@inject @jdbc` to initialize `employeesRepo` and it is not getting initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054258/jdbc-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) confirms that you were trying to follow [this tutorial](http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet/JSP_tutorial_:_Adding_MySQL_and_JDBC_to_bookstore_example). It is however targeted on [Caucho Resin](http://www.caucho.com/), a full fledged Java EE application server which supports all the Java EE fanciness out the box without the need to add some more JARs.

You, however, are using Tomcat. Tomcat is a barebones JSP/Servlet container which doesn't support all the other Java EE fanciness out the box. It supports only [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). The `@Inject`, which is part of the CDI, wouldn't have been importable in your Java servlet code in first place. That you got it to compile can only mean that you downloaded some JAR containing `javax.inject.Inject` and dropped it in runtime classpath.

This isn't the way how to install CDI in Tomcat. You'd need to do a bit more work. See also among others [Weld (the CDI reference implementation) documentation on Tomcat](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e4998).

---

I would however recommend to stop reading that tutorial, it isn't exactly a very nice introdcuction to Java EE (the `@JDBC` annotation is at its own also somewhat a "wtf?") and look for another tutorial, or better, a real book. If you want seriously learn Java EE, then I'd also recommend to replace Tomcat by a real Java EE application server, such as [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/), [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net), [JBoss AS](http://jboss.org/jbossas), etc. They all ship with CDI out the box (and JPA and EJB which are way much better than JDBC).

Comment: I followed a tutorial on how to install Weld with Tomcat and the `nullpointer exception` error stopped appearing for the employeesRepo. It still does show up, however, but now for a variable that should hold connection to database. Overall, though that means that I installed CDI and injection works?

Comment: If `@Inject`ed resources doesn't leave you with `null`, then yes, you may assume that you got CDI to work in Tomcat properly.